# Syntax clash when using maven filters for shell script files

Tags: shell, maven, syntax, filtering

Has anyone else wondered why Maven filtering uses a syntax that is valid in a shell script: ${foo} ? If I add Maven filtering to my shell script, I run the risk that my shell script variables are confused with Maven properties. Is it possible to get around this, for instance by using a different syntax for this case of Maven filtering?

Best regards
Trond

Comment: Please show your pom file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the delimiters parsed by maven can be re-configured in the resources plugin. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#delimiters

so you can use different markers to not mess up your scripts.